# Python performance difference between dictionary look-ups (string keys) to list indexing

Tags: python, performance, list, dictionary, optimization

Compared to indexing list using integers, i.e. `l[4]`, how slow is indexing a Python dictionary that use short strings for keys? I know the theoretical worst-case here; but is Python doing any optimizations under the hood making the practical difference negligible?

My keys are either a single lowercase letter or two uppercase letters making for *at most* 26+26*26=702 keys. The average number of keys is very small, < 50. Extending the existing solution to convert keys into integers, adjusting for gaps, and using lists instead of dictionaries is not a hard problem but if the performance difference is negligible then there is not really any point.

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see that indexing is the performance bottleneck?

Comment: Dict-acces is slow compared to random-access (you need to hash after all; ignoring collisions; ignoring cache-effects). If this hurts your task, will depend on your task.

Comment: You could probably measure it yourself with profiling, or event just timeit.

Comment: The point of dictionaries, is that ususally a lookup should not scale (much) with the *number* of keys. Worst case it is *O(n)*. But in almost all cases a lookup is *O(1)*.

Comment: If you keys are variable length strings, then converting them to integers to use as a list index is essentially hashing them, except now you would be doing the hashing at the Python level, rather than more efficiently inside the interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that lists are faster:

[LIST](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1vBViE6UUFLwdDIQkFbIQnOSoay0vKLFBIVMvMUihLz0lM1gEKaYLEkLGLJqGKxXDkg0w1ioUYhkVyZuQX5RSUKJZm5qVzFJYlApi2YowciNDS5QMZ5g4zLtlLIifaO5Sooyswr0UBSoqCrANao@f8/AA)

[DICT](https://tio.run/##bYxBCsIwEEX3OcVfJoiCupFCT5AjlC7SUE1om4TpbEQ8e2xaRAU3w5vHm0l3djGccx5Qo7GOpFHYoUD3BqtwjQQDH0Am3Hp5PF021/1x9te1YlxePzQqODM7qbdKl2p4Cj@lSAz2Uy9mNgvW63IoQyrxaSuMjW5FIh9YfiXYYz1UOb8A)

This makes sense: **random access by numbers works fairly quickly**, but with dict keys, the **getter must first be hashed** which slows it down significantly enough that you can kind of notice the distance after `128 ** 3` accesses.

Really, **the difference is negligible**, and depending on your uses, a dict may be better where you need `key: value`. For speed though, lists are better, but **if your access keys aren't just integers, dicts are probably better**.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. I am analysing an algorithm for a course and I could either use dictionaries in the algorithm (legible, understandable, etc.) or do an up-front computation from keys -> indexes myself outside of the algorithm and utilise lists alone which will be faster but maybe nominally so.

Comment: @FilipAllberg I'd recommend dicts. The difference is fairly negligible unless you have 128^3 values (you only have 706 so this shouldn't be a problem). Dicts are probably also more readable for your purposes